# How can I recover data from SRAM?

Tags: pic

I am using 23LC1024 SRAM with PIC32MX250F128B. I am collecting data from a sensor which is being stored in the SRAM and displaying it through a serial monitor. If I lose that data is there any way I can recover it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Soon after you remove power from the SRAM chip, it will read 0xff from each location, and whatever was there prior to power cycle will be gone forever.

Answer (score 0):

SRAM means Static Random-Access Memory.
It is a type of semiconductor memory that uses bistable latching, but is still volatile in the conventional sense that data is lost when the memory is not powered.

You don't have to refresh the SRAM compared to the DRAM periodically, that's the advantage.
But remember, there is no save way to reconstruct your data after a power down of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Cold boot attack might still possible.

In fact, computer memory is capable of retaining much of its previous contents without power for seconds in DRAM/SDRAM [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, and 36] and minutes in SRAM, [ref](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a545078.pdf)

Try to read, after reboot.